# How to make a non-background image display in the center of a smaller div

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div style="width:400px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;">
  <img src="http://d39kbiy71leyho.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/09170020/cats-politics-TN.jpg" />
</div>
```

Here is the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mddc/j2vw29c6/12/

The image is 600px in width. It cannot be a background image. So the image's center in the width direction is not displayed in the center (width direction) of the parent div. Note that the image cannot be responsive.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yrad9em8/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

meet the command which basically center everything :)

```
top: 50%; left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j2vw29c6/14/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` on the container.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* width-direction center */
  align-items: center; /*height-direction center */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://d39kbiy71leyho.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/09170020/cats-politics-TN.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I cannot add css to the image container.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flex layout](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) introduced in CSS3. Refer below CSS

```css
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:400px;height:300px;overflow:hidden;" class="flex-container">
  <img src="http://d39kbiy71leyho.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/09170020/cats-politics-TN.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I cannot add css to the image container.